# How to add data to related table in Auth Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use the standard mechanism authentication in Laravel 5.3 is built by command:`php artisan make:auth`.

So, It have created controller `RegisterController` with the following methods:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]));
    }
```

So, I need to extend this method that to add data to related table for User table. For this I do:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ])->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', "admin"))->first());
    }
```

After this I get error:

```
FatalThrowableError in SessionGuard.php line 441:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use Laravel's auth logic, but it looks like the user gets logged in right after they're created. To log the user in Laravel needs the User object, hence:

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);
```

The `create()` method [returns](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_create) `Model`. You, however, added `attach()` to the return statement, and if you take a look at the API, the method [returns](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_attach) `void` which eventually translates to `null` mentioned in the error message.

What you want to do, is something like this:

```
protected function create(array $data) {

    // Create the User and store the object
    $newUser = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    // Add extra data
    $adminRole = Role::where('name', 'like', 'admin')->first();
    $newUser->roles()->attach($adminRole->id);

    // Return the new User object
    return $newUser;
}
```

Note: I assumed you have an `id` column in your `role(s)` table.